# Making a Auto FillRange

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried to make this Auto Fill Range on VBA but I don't know What is Wrong or even if it works.
it should fill all the ranges A1 to Z20 based on first and second cells of each columns.
If anyone else can do it works or what's wrong please fix it.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Range
Dim a As Long

Do While Not Range("Z20").Value > 0
If a = 0 Then
a = 1
Else
End If

For Each i In Range("A:Z")
a = a + 1
i = Range(Cells(1, a), Cells(20, a))
Cells(1, a).Value = 1
Cells(2, a).Value = 2

Set SourceRange = Range(Cells(1, a), Cells(2, a))
Set fillRange = Range(i).Columns(a)
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
Next
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim c As Range
Dim a As Long
Dim sourceRange As Range

a = 1
Do While a <> 20
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, a) = 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, a) = 2
Set c = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, a), Cells(20, a))

Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, a), Cells(2, a))

sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=c

a = a + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. Adding "Option Explicit" at the top of your code would help a lot in finding issues.